# Handle multiple events on a HTML table row

Tags: jquery, events, html-table

I have an HTML table which has an onClick property on the row which navigates me to another page.
On this table I want to add a button, or an anchor tag which should do something else; e.g delete the row of that table.

By default, on clicking the button, it executes that JS function and then the Row JS function.
How can I set it so that it does not execute the Row event?

I am using JQuery to bind the table row

```
$('#table-control-data >tr', jqueryContext).live('click', HandleAction);
```

Comment: Which browser(s) are you testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
return false;
```

at the end of the function that is being invoked by the button.

Use **[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)** inside the button click.

Comment: Tried that, but it still goes into the row event.